# Canonical copy showing way above the original in search results

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical

On February 1st, I uploaded a blog story to my personal website.

On February 11th, it was indexed by Google.

On February 13th, I uploaded the same story to Medium, with a canonical URL pointing to the original on my website.

Today, I found that the Medium story is on page 1 of Google for a search phrase, and the original from my website is nowhere to be found in the first 5 pages.

When I search it with site:example.com then I can find it, so it's definitely available to Google.

Based on this, it appears to me that there is no benefit to the canonical URL.

What can I do to make sure the original blog story gets ranked higher than the Medium copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google docs state that you state your preference for the canonical page, but it will do what it wants based on other factors.

> There are a handful of factors that play a role in canonicalization: whether the page is served via HTTP or HTTPS, redirects, presence of the URL in a sitemap, and rel="canonical" link annotations. You can indicate your preference to Google using these techniques, **but Google may choose a different page as canonical than you do**, for various reasons. That is, indicating a canonical preference is a hint, not a rule.

And

> If Google finds multiple pages that seem to be the same or the primary content very similar, it chooses the page that, based on the factors (or signals) the indexing process collected, is objectively the most complete and useful for search users, and marks it as canonical.

Full description at [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/canonicalization)

In your case, I think it means you have made a better job on your page on Medium.   You could check and compare the stats on both pages using any number of online checkers and follow their suggestions to improve your primary page.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be wise, then, to hold off on cross-posting new blog pieces to Medium for a while until my own domain's authority grows a bit?

Comment: I also wonder how they would feel if I just wrote a paragraph or two on Medium and then linked to the original, without a canonical.

Comment: Added a suggestion in my answer

Comment: As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.